# Calculate $dF/dt$ when $F(t)=f(x(t))$, $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ , $ x(t) = \cos(t) e_1 + 2 \sin(t) e_2 + t e_3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Calculate $dF/dt$ when $F(t)=f(x(t))$, $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ , $ x(t) = \cos(t) e_1 + 2 \sin(t) e_2 + t e_3$

So I need to calculate d$F$/dt and I'm not sure if I'm being really silly. But using chain rule I get that it is equal to (d$F$/dx)(dx/dt)

Basically is df/dx = 2||$x$||.dx/dt ?

Comment: Why not use $$F(t)=\cos^2t+4\sin^2t+t^2$$ and differentiate it?

Comment: @Did The question asks to do by chain rule. Like I did it this way and it was easy. But I don't know what the derivative of ||x||^2 is

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Euclidean norm so $f(x(t))$ for your specified x(t) is,
$f(x(t))=cos^2(t)+4sin^2(t)+t^2$. Taking the derivative of this wrt to t gives us
$F(t)=f'(x(t))=-2cos(t)sin(t)+8sin(t)cos(t)+2t$, then simplify if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Using chain rule, one has:
$$\dot{F}(t)=\mathrm{d}_{x(t)}f\cdot \dot{x}(t)=2\langle x(t),\dot{x}(t)\rangle.$$

Indeed, notice that:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+2\langle x,h\rangle+O(\|h\|^2),$$
with $h\mapsto 2\langle x,h\rangle$ being linear which gives $\mathrm{d}_xf$.